# Finding duplicate values in mysql when joining two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following 3 tables for students and I need to find the names of students who currently are enrolled in classes that meet at the same time

```
student(**snum**, sname, major, level, age)
class(**cname**, meets_at, room) 
enroll(**snum**, **cname**)
```

The keys for each table is in bold.

I have tried the folling code and I'm not sure whether I'm close to the correct answer here.

```
select s.sname
  from student s
  join
     ( select c.cname
            , c.meets_at
            , (count(*)
         from class c
       having count( * ) > 1
     ) e
    on c.cname = e.cname
   and s.snum = e.snum;
```

Comment: looks like my formatting did not work correctly, the stuff in **s is supposed to be bolded.

Comment: Hi, Yea looks like the bold formatter does not work inside a code block. So you may put the tables structure outside the code block or replace the name bolded with surrounded by **.

Comment: You can see that you're missing a GROUP BY clause, right?

Answer (score 0):

I would think of this as joining on students with `meetsat`.  So, this gets students with their class times:

```
select s.sname, c.meets_at
from students s join
     enrolls e
     on s.snum = e.snum join
     classes c
     on c.cname = e.cname;
```

Then, to get the duplicates, use aggregation and filter using `having`:

```
select s.snum, s.sname, c.meets_at, count(*) as cnt
from students s join
     enrolls e
     on s.snum = e.snum join
     classes c
     on c.cname = e.cname
group by s.snum, sname, c.meets_at
having count(*) >= 2;
```

Note that this includes the ids as well as the name, because two students could have the same name.

Finally, a student could have multiple pairs of classes that conflict, but you only want to see the student once.  Although the above is probably sufficient for your purposes, a more accurate solution for the stated problem would be:

```
select distinct s.sname
from students s join
     enrolls e
     on s.snum = e.snum join
     classes c
     on c.cname = e.cname
group by s.snum, sname, c.meets_at
having count(*) >= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select s.snum, s.sname, c.meets_at ,count(*) as cnt into #tempStudents 
from students s 
join enrolls e on s.snum = e.snum 
join classes c on c.cname = e.cname;
```

Put the whole data in temporary table

```
select sname from #tempStudents 
group by snum,sname ,meets_at  
having cnt >=2
```

Now apply filtration on temporary table  for getting desire data 
and if u need distinct name of student put **Distinct** keyword before **sname**.